# Webpack + Typscript library import is undefined in React project

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, babeljs

I am trying to make a React library using Typescript, Webpack and Babel however I am running into a problem. If I build then import the library into a React project then my import is 'undefined' (See the below error). I think this would be because in the `bundle.js` there is no `module.exports` for the variable that would represent my class there is only a `__webpack_exports__["default"] = (ExampleComponent);` (However I am unsure of what this does in practice so I could be wrong.)

I specifically got this error:

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

What I have tried:

- Changing the tsconfig target to es6 and module to commonjs
- Changing the tsconfig target to es6 and module to esnext
- Changing the tsconfig target to es5 and module to esnext
- Changing the tsconfig target to esnext and module to esnext
- Changing the tsconfig target to es6 and module to es6
- Changing the tsconfig target to commonjs and module to es6
- Importing the library as 'import * as ExampleComponent from ...' and 'import {ExampleComponent} from ...' (As intended) both times 'ExampleComponent' was undefined.

Versions:

- babel-loader: ^8.1.0
- Webpack: ^4.43.0
- typescript: ^3.8.3

Code:

**React Project:**

```
import React from "react";
import { ExampleComponent } from "test-lib";

// This is always undefined
console.log(ExampleComponent);

function App() {
    return <ExampleComponent />;
}

export default App;
```

**Library Project:**

index.ts:

```
import ExampleComponent from './ExampleComponent'

export { ExampleComponent }
```

ExampleComponent.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react'
import './ExampleComponent.css'

interface Props {
    text: string
}

// prettier-ignore
const ExampleComponent: React.FC<Props> = ({ text }) => (
    <h1 className="example-text">{text}</h1>
)

export default ExampleComponent
```

**Library Configs:**

tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "dist",
        "module": "esnext",
        "lib": ["dom", "esnext"],
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "jsx": "react",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "allowJs": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "strict": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true
    },
    "include": ["src", "tests"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist", "example"]
}
```

**.babelrc:**

```
{
    "presets": [
        [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            {
                "debug": true,
                "useBuiltIns": "usage",
                "corejs": 3
            }
        ],
        "@babel/preset-react",
        "@babel/preset-typescript"
    ]
}
```

**Webpack Config:**

```
const path = require('path')
const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        bundle: './src/index.ts',
    },

    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].js',
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js', '.json'],
    },

    devtool: 'source-map',

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [{ loader: 'babel-loader' }, { loader: 'ts-loader' }],
            },

            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },

            {
                test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg)$/,
                use: [
                    'file-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
                        options: {
                            disable: true,
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },

            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                enforce: 'pre',
                loader: 'source-map-loader',
            },
        ],
    },

    plugins: [new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin()],
}
```

If you want to see the full code here is a link to the [Github Repo](https://github.com/robert-harbison/generator-react-typescript-library/tree/cleanup/generators/app/templates).

Comment: Have you looked at webpack's [`output.library`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibrary) config?

Comment: You are not importing React consistently. In one case you import it as if it were a `default` export but in the other you treat it as a set of named exports. Which is it?

Comment: @skovy Thanks I was able to get it working using the output.libraryTarget option.

Comment: great to hear! @RobertHarbison

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the comment from Scovy I was able to get this working by using the [output.libraryTarget](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/) and [output.globalObject](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/) output options.

Now my output entry in my webpack.base.config.js looks like this:

```
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    globalObject: 'this',
},
```

**Update:**

The above change did not seam to work 100% of the time so I found a library called [esm-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@purtuga/esm-webpack-plugin) which ended up working perfectly.

So the final code for the output entry in the webpack config is:

```
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    library: 'LIB',
    libraryTarget: 'var',
},
```

and I also added the plugin:

```
plugins: [new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin(), new EsmWebpackPlugin()],
```

Comment: you save my life